# does anyone know how to summarize the blog post?

Tags: post, blogger, summary

Does anyone know how I can put the blog to be summarized only in posts that I want? All tutorial for summary post, are automatic summaries and I do not want an automatic. Because some of my posts are small.

> Ps .: I'm not using the blog templete. i am using another one.

If anyone knows send there a website link to a tutorial or something like that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get used to use the "Jump break" feature that Blogger platform have by default when you are creating a new blog post.

This is the icon of the feature: [image: jumpbreak]

In most Blogger templates the template is coded for using "post summaries" as long as you add a "Jump break" into your post.

The logic is most cases is:

```
IF (post has jump break) show (post body til desired jump break)
ELSE show (full post body)
```

So if you get used to use the jump breaks you will be able to control how much content of your post will be displayed in the homepage and other index pages (search, label search, archive, newer/older links, etc.).